# Common Doubt:Why there is the difference in the answer? In chessboard 2 squares are selected...

Tags: probability, combinatorics

> If two of the 64 squares are slected at random on a chessboard, the probability that they have a side common is..... .

**Attempt**

Choosing the corner side and the required square is ${{4_{C_1}}*{2_{C_1}}}$

Choosing 4 corner sides remaing squares and the other required square is ${{24_{C_1}}*3}$

And other remaing squares ${36*4}$

And the total selection is ${64_{C_2}}$

But the probability is $\frac{1}{18}$ and I am getting $\frac{1}{9}$. Why?

**I have seen the same question on math stack exchange but was not able to connect to it. Also they don't answer the question that why my method has not been able to given the correct answer.**

**the answer given there by the user Jack  just states for numerator and says to divide it rather than explaining why to do it.**

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Your numerator counts ordered pairs, while your total selection counts unordered pairs. Divide your numerator by 2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because you overcount by a factor of $2$: if, for example, you first pick a corner square, and then a square adjacent under it, you end up with the same pair as when you first pick the square under the corner square, and then the corner square. Same goes for any pair of squares you end up with.

Here's a simple example that shows similar overcounting:

How many ways can you pick $2$ people out of $A,B,$ and $C$?  Well, for the first person you have $3$ options, and after that you have $2$ options for the second person, so it seems like you have $6$ options. But, you know that the answer should just be ${3 \choose 2} = 3$. And that's because the $6$ overcounts: because there is no order of the two people you pick, picking $A$ first, and then $B$ ends up with the same pair as picking $B$ first, and then $A$.